# jquery confirm plugin is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, confirm

I'm trying out the jquery plugin using jquery1.8.3. but event handler(**alerts**) is not working for either of the buttons.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button class="confirm" type="button">Delete the comment</button>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.confirm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".confirm").confirm({
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete that comment?",
    title: "Confirmation required",
    confirm: function(button) {
        alert("foo")
    },
    cancel: function(button) {
        alert("bar")
    },
    confirmButton: "Yes I am",
    cancelButton: "No",
    post: true
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

any clue ?

Comment: If you look at the Requirements, it says **Bootstrap 3 for the modals**

Comment: updated code for bootstrap3 but there is error in confirm.js file at modal.modal('show');

Comment: If you use the css also, it works fine [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L7yuL/1/)

Comment: no errors now , but alert still not coming for either buttons instead whole modal is disaapearing

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".confirm").click(function(){
     $.confirm({
     'message': "Are you sure you want to delete that comment?",
     'title': "Confirmation required",

     'buttons': {
            'Yes': {

                'action': function(){
                   alert();
                   }
                 },
            'No': {

                'action': function(){
                   alert()
                }
              }
           });

        });

    });
```

I don't see why you put a button as parameter.

Comment: no luck. Althought the button can be used there // modal.find(".confirm").click(function () {
            settings.confirm(settings.button);
        });